# UIView changed when something is added programmatically - Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2, uicontainerview

I am working on an app for iPad. In this app, I use a Container View Controller and a View Controller. Before the question, let me show you how it works:

[image]

And my Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var blueView: UIView!

    var frameSize: CGSize!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        frameSize = self.view.frame.size
        containerView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width - containerView.frame.width, y: 0)

        let deviceSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 667)

        blueView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: frameSize.width / 2 - deviceSize.width / 2 - containerView.frame.width / 2, y: frameSize.height / 2 - deviceSize.height / 2), size: deviceSize)      

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)))
        button.titleLabel?.text = "Button Test"
        button.backgroundColor = .redColor()

        blueView.addSubview(button)

    }

}
```

I run it, and everything occurs as expected.

[image]

The problem is, when I touch the screen, running code in touchesBegan.

The problem is add programativamente anything. I can't fix it. And my screen looks like this:

[image]

I can't identify what the origin and size change when I add something programmatically.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the option '**Use Auto Layout**'. Let **disabled** to solve the problem.

[image]